# Getting back slashes in the json/request body in Lua script

Tags: json, lua, kong, cjson

While writing Lua script for kong plugin, we are observed that in the encoded body saw the back slashes and when we tried to decode getting error.

Please help to remove the backslashes to decode successfull

Below is the snippet we tried

```lua
local json =require "cjson"

body=json.encode(response)
util.application_logging():debug("encoded body"..util.dump(body))
```

//Here getting as below

```json
body{\"mobileno\":\"98765467\",\"pwd\":\"demo123\"}
```

```lua
body =json.decode(body);
```

//not getting anything

Comment: just an additional thing need to inform - Before encode() method, when I tried to print 'response' , I got the table.

Comment: Backslashes are shown by `util.dump`.  They are absent in JSON.  You can try `print(body:byte(1,-1))` to see all ASCII codes.